# SQL need to add outerjoin to the query below

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below SQL:

I need to add two columns in the result

```
1) Local_code     
2)Local_CPTY_SYS_ID,
```

which are in `HSBC_LOCAL_INVOL_PARTY` table.

So far I have tried to add

```
select local_code from HSBC_LOCAL_INVOL_PARTY
 h join t_cdr T2 
on T2.counterparty_new = h.entity_code
```

but that doesn't work. It needs an explicit outer join in the end. Please help

```
SELECT
T2.counterparty_new,
T2.bis_entity_type_original,
T2.counterparty_new_desc,
T2.counterparty_new_attribute_6,
T2.method_original,
T2.netting_agreement_reference, 
T2.internal_rating_new, 
T2.counterparty_type_original, 
T2.obligor_grade_new, 
T2.pd_pre_floor_new,
T2.pd_new,
T2.lgd, 
T2.rwa 
from  t_cdr T2,
(
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
FINAL.FILTER_MARKER,
FINAL.entity_code
FROM (
SELECT 
FILTER_POP.entity_code,
FILTER_POP.FILTER_MARKER
FROM (
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN CONCAT(Dlgd,unfloored_lgd)  IS NOT NULL
THEN  'EXCLUDE'
WHEN CONCAT(Dlgd,unfloored_lgd)  IS NULL
THEN 'INCLUDE'
END AS  FILTER_MARKER,
entity_code, 
Dlgd,
unfloored_lgd
FROM 
HSBC_LOCAL_INVOL_PARTY 
WHERE 
 ((HSBC_LOCAL_INVOL_PARTY.entity_code) NOT LIKE '%DUM%')
AND 
((HSBC_LOCAL_INVOL_PARTY.entity_code) NOT LIKE '%HSBC%')
)  FILTER_POP
GROUP BY 
FILTER_POP.entity_code,
FILTER_POP.FILTER_MARKER) FINAL
GROUP BY 
FINAL.FILTER_MARKER,
FINAL.entity_code
ORDER BY 
FINAL.entity_code)
PIVOT
(
COUNT(FILTER_MARKER)
FOR FILTER_MARKER IN ('INCLUDE' AS INCLUDE,'EXCLUDE' AS EXCLUDE)
)
WHERE INCLUDE = 1 AND EXCLUDE = 0
) ENTITY_FILTER
WHERE ENTITY_FILTER.entity_code = T2.counterparty_new
AND T2.method_original = 'ADV' 
ORDER  BY T2.rwa DESC
```

Comment: Minimize the problem. (If you need to scroll, it's way too big...)

Comment: Just put a "Sombody else's problem" sticker on it. Now really - can you read this question?

Comment: see the link referenced to know on  how to ask a perfect question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @jarth, that is a ridiculous comment. If the Sql containing the issue is long, we need to see all of it to figure it out because we don't know where teh problem is.

Comment: Stop using the SQL antipattern of implicit joins.

Comment: Right!! Basically you have no idea how to resolve the problem, so the problem is wrong!! The above has been written to minimize the query running time. The logic in between is complicated by the nature of the problem it is trying to resolve. If you have something better in mind please do post. Would really appreciate if you don't think that everyone posting is an idiot.

Comment: You'll get a better response if you explain what exactly you mean by "that doesn't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: Look at the last few lines. Took a while but optimized it as well for performance.

```
SELECT
T2.counterparty_new,
T2.bis_entity_type_original,
T2.counterparty_new_desc,
T2.counterparty_new_attribute_6,
T2.method_original,
T2.netting_agreement_reference, 
T2.internal_rating_new, 
T2.counterparty_type_original, 
T2.obligor_grade_new, 
T2.pd_pre_floor_new,
T2.pd_new,
T2.lgd, 
HSBC_LOCAL_INVOL_PARTY.local_code,
T2.rwa 
from  t_cdr T2,
(
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
FINAL.FILTER_MARKER,
FINAL.entity_code
FROM (
SELECT 
FILTER_POP.entity_code,
FILTER_POP.FILTER_MARKER
FROM (
SELECT
CASE 
WHEN CONCAT(Dlgd,unfloored_lgd)  IS NOT NULL
THEN  'EXCLUDE'
WHEN CONCAT(Dlgd,unfloored_lgd)  IS NULL
THEN 'INCLUDE'
END AS  FILTER_MARKER,
entity_code, 
Dlgd,
unfloored_lgd
FROM 
HSBC_LOCAL_INVOL_PARTY 
WHERE 
 ((HSBC_LOCAL_INVOL_PARTY.entity_code) NOT LIKE '%DUM%')
AND 
((HSBC_LOCAL_INVOL_PARTY.entity_code) NOT LIKE '%HSBC%')
)  FILTER_POP
GROUP BY 
FILTER_POP.entity_code,
FILTER_POP.FILTER_MARKER) FINAL
GROUP BY 
FINAL.FILTER_MARKER,
FINAL.entity_code
ORDER BY 
FINAL.entity_code)
PIVOT
(
COUNT(FILTER_MARKER)
FOR FILTER_MARKER IN ('INCLUDE' AS INCLUDE,'EXCLUDE' AS EXCLUDE)
)
WHERE INCLUDE = 1 AND EXCLUDE = 0
) ENTITY_FILTER,HSBC_LOCAL_INVOL_PARTY
WHERE ENTITY_FILTER.entity_code = T2.counterparty_new 
AND ENTITY_FILTER.entity_code = HSBC_LOCAL_INVOL_PARTY.entity_code(+)
AND T2.method_original = 'ADV' 
ORDER  BY T2.rwa DESC
```